# Как сделать чтобы по клику на ссылку div не разворачивался.

Tags: jquery, css

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entry').hide()
    $('.click').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    })
})
```

По клику на div class="click" разворачивается div class="entry". Подскажите, а как сделать, чтобы если кликаешь на ссылку, которая находится внутри div class="click" - не происходило разворачивания ?

```
<div class="click">
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=704" rel="bookmark">WordPress</a>
</div>
<div class="entry">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.entry').hide();
$('.click').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName != 'A'){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Так почему то вообще не работает.

Comment: @Yupi, код в DOM-Ready обернули?


P.S. В общем, поку думаете, вот [рабочий пример][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/T9LZE/

Comment: добавил после /body заработало ) спасибо за помощь )))